# Slideshow screensaver with dual-monitor support?

Tags: windows-7, screensaver, multiple-monitors

I have a dual-monitor setup at home + work and want to show off my panoramas on them when they're not busy. I'm looking for a program that supports the following:

- wide-screen images (and panoramas) across both screens
- sub-directories
- automatic crop/shrink images that are too big
- *(optional bonus)* allow input e.g. left/right to go back/forward (like Win7's included screensaver)
- *(optional bonus)* quick and simple fade transition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Google Photos Screensaver. This is part of Picasa (in Picasa, click the Tools menu and select Configure Screensaver.)

Not only does it display on both screens but it also can show different photos on each monitor.